# allowing all HTML tags in tinymce editor

Tags: tinymce, wp-editor

I have a plugin where I am creating a shortcode that creates a form with a textarea field. I would like the user to be able to insert a complete HTML page into the editor - including the HTML and BODY tags and allow all HTML tags. Whenever I switch from Text to Visual view, paragraph tags get added and all but the H1 tags get removed.

I've tried several methods.

Method 1:

```
$html_code = "<html><head><title>title of page</title></head><body><h1>Page Heading</h1></body></html>"
$editor_id = "template_code";
$settings = array('textarea_name' => $editor_id, 'tinymce' => array ('toolbar1'=> 'bold,italic'), 'valid_elements'=>'*[*]');
wp_editor ( $html_code, $editor_id, $settings );
```

The toolbar settings are working, but the valid_elements has no effect.

Method 2:

```
function my_format_TinyMCE( $in ) {
    $in['toolbar1'] = 'bold';
    $in['toolbar2'] = 'italic';
    $in['valid_elements'] = '*[*]';
    $in['verify_html'] = false;
}
add_filter ( 'tiny_mce_before_init', 'my_Format_TinyMCE' );
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/tiny_mce_before_init

And some that I can't remember.

It this even possible? If so, what am I missing?

TIA!!!

Answer (score 5):

Try this function from [leighton.com](http://www.leighton.com/blog/stop-tinymce-in-wordpress-3-x-messing-up-your-html-code) :

```
function override_mce_options($initArray) {
    $opts = '*[*]';
    $initArray['valid_elements'] = $opts;
    $initArray['extended_valid_elements'] = $opts;
    return $initArray;
}
add_filter('tiny_mce_before_init', 'override_mce_options');
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to use the fullpage plugin.
See: http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Plugin3x:fullpage